# Prevent beamer columns environment from adding vertical space

Tags: beamer, columns, block

the beamer columns environment adds vertical space before the content of the columns, which becomes particularly obvious (and ugly) when used within a block:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Frame}
        
        \begin{block}{itemize with columns}
            \begin{columns}
                \begin{column}{\textwidth}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 1
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{column}
                \end{columns}
            \end{block}
        
        \begin{block}{tcolorbox with columns}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                This is a box.
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{block}

        \begin{block}{itemize without columns}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
            \end{itemize}
\end{block}

        \begin{block}{tcolorbox without columns}
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                This is a box.
            \end{tcolorbox}
\end{block}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Until now, I have used \vspace to fix it locally, but it's getting too much hassle, and I would like to fix this once and for all.

Is there a way to prevent columns from adding this space?

Comment: you could use T-alignment `\begin{column}[T]{\textwidth}`. But why do you use columns at all in a block? seems a bit overdoing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using the [T] doesn't remove all of the space though. As for your question, I sometimes need colums to fit several short words into a limited vertical space. For an example, you can look at page 153 in this document: http://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~hladik/Logik/Logik-handout.pdf

Comment: you can always use `blocks` inside minipages instead of columns. this way you avoid the space above text. And `columns` are ignored in case you want to use the beamer contents into an article.

Comment: Ignasi, but then I would have a smaller block. What I need is a block spanning the entire page, with the content arranged in several columns.

Comment: Or did you mean using minipages inside the box? That's possible, but then I can't easily align the minipages, as with \begin{columns}[b] etc.